# Nautilus desktop icon not showing "Places" anymore

Tags: nautilus

Not sure what exactly caused it but today after I managed to crash nautilus again, my Files app aka Nautilus stopped showing **Places** under its right-click menu.

Here you can see how the right click menu looks right now:

[image]

I'm also unable to open multiple instances of Nautilus, when I right click on it and select the Files option, it will just raise the existing one.

Anyone know of some way to fix this?

EDIT: I am actually able to open multiple instances but only from the dash.

Answer (score 2):

Seems I fixed it by copying the `nautilus.desktop` from `/usr/share/applications` to

```
~/.local/share/applications.
```

Had to add this to the end of the file:

```
[Documents Shortcut Group]
Name=Documents
Exec=nautilus --new-window Documents
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

And then dragging the file to my dash bar.
Without the added lines, it acted the same way still,  only difference was that it had the New Window option in it. Bugs me how that stuff I added in the end fixed it because I did not even define the launcher to use that entry.